# Admin Sidebar not appearing in one view in J5 component

Tags: administrator, joomla-5.x, sidebar

So I have rewritten one of my j3 components for J5, hopefully following the new standards (my first attempt)

All admin views work fine except for one where the admin sidebar does not appear (as if it was an edit view, which it isn't)

I cannot see any significant difference in Controller, Model, View, or tmpl between the broken view and the working ones.

The new view entry appears ok in the sidebar menu in the other views, but when the view opens there is no sidebar.

Namespace statement is correct (and the same in controller and model) for both faulty and good views

Use clauses in the faulty view are the same as in good ones (with some additions and unused ones removed per file as appropriate)

HtmlView extends BaseHtml view in both working and faulty views, same use clauses are present and same functions ( display() and addToolbar() )

Model extends ListModel for both working and the faulty view. The faulty one only has the same functions by name and signature as does another working one.

Controller extends AdminController in both cases and has only one function getModel() which is the same as others - it simply calls the parent getModel()

There is no Table or Form for the view - it is simply displaying static information - another very similar view works ok, as do conventional list views.

My surface question is for any clues as to what could possibly be going wrong, and underneath that what determines whether the Admin sidebar will be displayed or not?

Answer (score 0):

Stupid schoolboy error by myself. Just in case anyone else does this I found I had
`Factory::getApplication()->getInput()->set('hidemainmenu', true);`  set in the view code and it took me ages to spot it in the middle of a block of useful code.
The perils of copy and paste combined with word blindness when comparing with a working view. :Doh: